# Efficient storage of time-series data with rarely-changing variables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, timescaledb

I must store and analyse time-series data received from several devices.
Each device is emitting data every 20 ms and lots of variables shall be stored (50+).
Some data are changing at each sample, *but other discrete data (enums or booleans) are less frequently changing (See example below)*.

Currently, i'm using TimescaleDb fed by Python (pandas) and data's are split over several tables by grouping data depending of their typical variation rate. Only changes are stored. At the end the data volume is really optimized with this approach.

However i'm having troubles to analyse this data, as typically i must run queries and know the value of all "Data_x" values on a given "timestamp".
Currently, it requires some complex reconstruction process using "*Last-Observation-Carried_Forward*" etc.

Would there be a better solution ?

**Full data set**

| Timestamp | Data_1 | Data_2 | Data_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:43.000 | 22.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:44.000 | 25.4 | 0 | **1** |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:45.000 | 29.2 | **1** | 0 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:46.000 | 31.3 | **1** | 0 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:47.000 | 31.4 | **1** | 0 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:48.000 | 33.7 | 0 | **1** |

**Data_1 table**

| Timestamp | Data_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:43.000 | 22.2 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:44.000 | 25.4 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:45.000 | 29.2 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:46.000 | 31.3 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:47.000 | 31.4 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:48.000 | 33.7 |

**Data_2_and_3 table** *(Note that there are only 4 samples in the table, as only the changes are recorded.*

| Timestamp | Data_2 | Data_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:43.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:44.000 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:45.000 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-06-12 17:52:48.000 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: It might help to generally describe the types of queries and types of info and what the different tables contain. Also how long you need to keep results of those queries, etc. Is Postgres the only repository of the source information? If you have the raw data stored elsewhere for example, you can potentially use Postgres's foreign data wrapper functionality to query the raw data directly when you need deeper analytics.

Comment: [`staircase`](https://www.staircase.dev) might help here, depending what you want to do with it.  It'll work efficiently for storing, and working with stepfunction data.

Answer (score 0):

> having troubles to analyse this data...
> Would there be a better solution ?

Hard to say. You didn't really give us a description of
the analysis challenges.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

---

The central problem seems to be how to boil down "too much data"
into fewer rows.

For the dataframe approach you're currently using,
with 1-second fixed-resolution timestamps across data_{1,2,3},
there's little choice but to synthesize those "carried forward" values.

A bottom-up compression approach, starting with the data,
would ignore irrelevant columns and then suppress any unchanged rows.
This might compress 3600 observations in an hour down to just a few hundred if there's intervals with little change.

A top-down compression approach, from the application side,
would have you focus on just the timestamps of interest
to the app, perhaps at 3-second intervals.
Something could change more quickly, but the app doesn't care.
This might be a better fit for a custom postgres query.

You didn't describe your app. Perhaps it doesn't really require
isochronous samples, and suppressing "too frequent" observations
would suffice. So if you're shooting for nominal 3-second intervals
and there were observations at noon +0, +1, and +5 seconds,
the +1 reading is suppressed and in practice we wind up with a 5-second interval.

---

When aggregating / suppressing observations,
you are free to choose from

- first
- last
- min
- max
- median
- avg
- imputed (interpolated)

according to your app's high-level needs.

---

Define a loss metric, such as "% error".

Aggregate your data at K-second intervals,
K ranging from maybe .1 to 600,
and evaluate the loss relative to
computing with smallest possible interval.

Having weighed the tradeoffs, choose a value of K
that lets your app compute acceptably fast
with acceptably low loss.

---

Maybe you are performing a time domain analysis
of data that is more naturally viewed in the frequency domain.
In which case [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) is your friend.
Augmenting each timestamp with "delta time since value last changed"
might go a long way to simplifying your data processing task.